# Property 'center' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MapContainerProps' on Leaflet

Tags: typescript, leaflet, react-typescript

I'm trying to implement a simple map on my app, but I'm getting this error while using the sample code below from React Leaflet.

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
            <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

The error:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; center: number[]; zoom: number; scrollWheelZoom: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MapContainerProps'.
  Property 'center' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MapContainerProps'.  TS2322

    150 |                     />
    151 | 
  > 152 | <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        |               ^
    153 |   <TileLayer
    154 |     attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    155 |     url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
```

I'm using React and Typescript.

Comment: did you install the react-leaflet types? `npm i -D @types/react-leaflet`?

Comment: Oh, that was the problem. I had installed only @types/leaflet. Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

My issue was that even when I had react-leaflet types installed, I still needed to install types for leaflet:

```
npm i -D @types/leaflet
```

Answer (score 8):

try to install leaflet types:

```
yarn add -D @types/react-leaflet
```

then restart your project.

Comment: I don't know what the react-leaflet package is, but I must use the `@types/leaflet` instead to fix the error. With the other one it doesn't work. And i cannot find to npmjs page :S

Answer (score 6):

2023 update I had to install both types (react-leaflet & leaflet)

```
npm i -D @types/leaflet @types/react-leaflet
```

https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-installation/#typescript-support

Comment: `@types/react-leaflet` is not necessary.

Comment: @Tonatio if something changed I have not been updated but this was indeed the solution last year. I will have to come back to this on a given chance, thanks for your input.